# Best course of study for learning to build electrical systems and supporting electronics for an off grid power station

Tags: electricity, electricity-generation

I'm working on constructing a totally self sufficient (i.e. **totally off grid**) building in the wild.

I do not want to restrict myself to any particular source of power (hydro, solar, wind etc), but I want to build up my knowledge of electrical power systems (and supporting electronic circuitry such as invertors/ voltage boosters etc).

The goal being that I will be able to create a composite power system that:

1. Combines multiple power sources of different types (DC/AC) and different voltages and currents
2. Produces an A/C output of a required frequency, current and voltage

Wherever possible, I would also like to be able to build the circuitry required (inverters, balance of system etc.)

I was a passionate electronics enthusiast in my youth - so I have some basic electronics experience (though most forgotten - the interest is still there), I am a software engineer by profession - so programming microcontrollers/EPROMS etc is something I can definitely do.

My question then is this:

Given the objectives listed above, what is the best course of study (links please) to help build the competence level required to do build my own power system as described above.

**Note:** I am fully aware that power systems can be lethal if appropriate care is not taken - I can assure you that I will always verify from a professional, before I do anything - so don't worry!.

Does this question belong in engineering?

Comment: I feel this would be better suited to the Electrical Engineering SE site http://electronics.stackexchange.com/, but perhaps it's worth seeing if you get an answer here anyway.

Comment: And this would seem to be impossibly broad. You're asking how to become a highly-skilled electrical and electronics engineer; that sounds like a six-year training programme. That's not something we can really handle on any Stack Exchange.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers Not really, in terms of electricity, I'm only asking of the knowledge required to combine different voltages and currents - no disrespect, but this should be [relatively straightforward](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21882/mixing-multiple-power-sources). In terms of the electronics, there are only a fixed number of devices (AFAIK) - namely; invertors, phasor measusrement units and voltage regulators. This is the lay man's view (i.e. mine, from what I've gathered so far) - I would like the view of someone who's actually implemented such a system.

Comment: Don't forget that you also need (or are required, if you have fire insurance) to build a *safe* installation. It is not *that* straightforward.

Comment: @JanDoggen: That (i.e. safety aspect) is taken as a given. What I want to do, is basically come up with the basics of a system that meets my goals and required functionality - and then get a professional electrical engineer (acting in the role of a consultant) to "kick the tires" and suggest improvements/modifications etc where needed

Comment: I'm voting to close as too broad. There are dozens of topics in this question... power conversion, power electronics, electrical safety, power system control, energy storage, wind/solar power siting, etc. I recommend picking one aspect of an off-grid power system to ask about first.

Comment: @LShaver so many assumptions on your part .... The only thing I'm asking for information on (in case it wasn't clear), is power conversation (specifically: combining multiple power sources into a single constant voltage, constant current output).

Comment: OK, in that case, it sounds like you first would need to learn about inverters, micro-grid control, chargers, etc. Then once you've got that under your belt you could start to consider which of those individual components you wanted to build on your own.

Comment: While the answers would be more engineering.SE the topic has sufficient interest to sustainability to allow to remain.  This is one that should be cross posted if such were possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is very likely you have already checked this but if you have not: http://www.earthship.org, they have some designs combining wind and solar.

If your terrain has a good water current you can also apply a water mill generator (depending on climate could be your most reliable energy source). You can put converters in your circuit but it is best to first plan your consumption (with some proper forecast if you see yourself expanding your electrical consumption) and then design the best system to fit your needs.

I am also planning to build a completely off-grid home and would be very keen to share plans with you if you are interested.

Comment: +1 and thanks for the sharing the link, I hadn't come across it before. I'll take a look later on, and see if it is suitable for an answer.

Comment: You may also want to check these: 
Monolithic dome structures: http://www.monolithic.org/

Affordable (and very smart building material) construction: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rBBSrdCYsvA&t=2s

Cool dome built in panels idea: http://www.i-domehouse.com/movie.html